# Recursive merge sort isn't sorting the array

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm trying to implement the merge sort algorithm using recursion. I'm not sure what the issue with my code is. It returns the original array without sorting it.

```java
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] a) {
        if(a.length < 2){
            return a;
        }
        int start = 0;
        int middle = a.length / 2;
        int end = a.length;
        //split the array 
        int[] left = mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, start, middle));
        int[] right = mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, middle, end));

        //merge them
        return merge(left, right);
    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int indexa = 0; int indexb = 0; int i =0;
        //create new array with combined length
        int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
        //copy elements to new array while sorting it
        while (indexa < a.length && indexb < b.length) {
            if (a[indexa] < b[indexb]) {
                c[i++] = a[indexa++];
            } else if (a[indexa] > b[indexb]){
                c[i++] = b[indexb++];
            }
        }

        //if one array is longer than the other copy remaining elements
        while (indexa < a.length) {
                c[i++] = a[indexa++];

        }
        while (indexb < b.length) {
                c[i++] = b[indexb++];
            }
        return c;

    }
```

Here's my main method as well

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {2, 1, 3, 4, 9, 6, 7};
        mergeSort(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));


    }
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: check the `main` method - it is just printing the input array, not the result - you want to print the array returned by `mergeSort()` || BTW posted code will probably fail if the array values are not unique (i.e. array contains duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    int[] b = mergeSort(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

The reason is your merge method copies your data to new array for sorting and returns that new array,
you are not doing it `in place`

Comment: Wouldn't `a = mergeSort(a);` also work?